# Clattering brakes on Liv Envie

Tags: brakes, carbon

My 2017 Liv Envie has 'V' style proprietary brakes (Giant Speed Control). Recently they've been making a clattering sounds when they engage the carbon wheel. This is happening on both the front and back wheels. Any ideas why?

Thank you!

Comment: it may be something to do with the carbon wheels they can make some funky noises in the wet and muddy, also if you could include some more details about what you riding (eg: CX, road, wet, dry)  :)

Comment: Presumably you checked that nothing is loose. Is the pad alignment well adjusted? Are the pads heavily worn?

Comment: "Clattering"? As in the sound that metal pan lids would make when dropped on the ground? Or chattering, as in making a rapid series of mid-to-high-pitched sounds?

Comment: How old are the pads?  IE how many KM have you done on the bike?  How's the wear on the pad?

Comment: I am riding a road bike in dry conditions. The break pads have maybe 2,000  on them.

Comment: 'Clattering' as in a vibration sounds hitting the carbon wheel. The breaks are still working. I get this clattering sound when I initial engage the breaks. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Brakes make sounds when:

1. Pads are worn out and metal plate of pads makes contact with the wheel.
2. Pads or wheels are dirty and greasy.
3. There is some loose part in braking mechanism.
4. Pads are rubbing against the wheel.
5. Overheating caused by long and hard braking.
6. Pads are wet.

To fix each of problems listed above do this :

1. Replace the pads.
2. Clean pads and wheels with some brake cleaner, degreaser or rubbing alcohol.
3. Tighten the loose part.
4. Straighten the wheel or align the pads.
5. Try to not brake if isn't necessary, or get better brakes that could handle the heat better.
6. If you are riding in wet conditions there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: 7. Pads are old and hardened, despite having a lot of meat left on the pad.  Can happen if bike has been stored for years, or pads are old stock - Replace with new pads.

Comment: 8. Pads are the wrong compound for your brake track. Carbon rims may have a carbon brake track, or may have an alloy track embedded in them.  If the pads are for the wrong surface, they won't work well and could damage the rim.

Comment: @Criggie: It's a 2017 bike so the pads are most certainly not old or hardened unless the have been replaced by such. I'd rather think #1 or #8 apply here.